# Random list of numbers and add them

Tags: python, random, sum, addition

I am trying to create a program that asks user for a number and then generates a list of random numbers entered by the user and then uses a function to add these numbers together and return it back to the main function. I am so lost can someone please help me?

```
import random

def main():
    rand = int(input('How many random intergers? (Max 20)'))
    if rand <= 20:
        for x in range(rand):
            print (random.randint(1,9), end=' ')
        total = randnums(x)
        print('Integers total is ', total)
    else:
        print('Bad inpit. Maximum input is 20.')
```

Trying to get this sample output

How many random integers (max 20)? 12

5 9 7 7 9 8 8 2 5 5 8 7

Integers total is 80

Comment: How can a list of numbers both come from the user and be randomly generated at the same time?

Comment: the user enters a number and then the program needs to put out that many random numbers

Comment: Hello David, welcome to SO. This site isn't meant to provide coding services, it is generally expected that you show at least some basic research, some code you created on your own, and ask help with specific problems. See [here for some general directions on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have done the code I have it generating the list i just cant figure out how to add it together

Comment: this is what i have so far I am looking i am looking in my text book and all over the web for help and dont know what im missing

Comment: You need to store the random integers you're generating so you can `sum()` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least to store your random outputs and only then you can add them...

E.G.

```
total = 0
for x in range(rand):
  rnum = random.randint(1,9)
  print (rnum, end=' ')
  total = total + rnum
print('Total: %s' %total)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
def f():
  n= input("give n : ")
  return sum([random.randint(0,10) for i in range(n)])
```

this will return the sum of  10 random number between 0 and 10

Answer (score 0):

Import random

print (sum ([random.random () for x in range (1,input ("choose a list size"))]))

Answer (score 0):

To sample *i* integers without replacement from a pool of integers from 1 to *n*, and then sum them:

```
$ n=12345
$ i=100
$ seq ${n} | shuf -n ${i} | awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}'
```

To sample with replacement and sum:

```
$ seq ${n} | shuf -r -n ${i} | awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}'
```